# PHP: the PHP_EOL in .txt file has been mistaken, how can I deal with it?

Tags: php, file-io

I'am working on a DES Encrypt/Decrypt homework. It requires turn 64-bits data(in my work it's string) into binary. After some kinds of calculate turn binary back to string. Here is my code:

```
/**
* turn string into binary
* @param type $str
* @return type
*/
function strToBin($str){

    //1.split characters
    $arr = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $str);

    //2.unpack characters
    foreach($arr as &$v){
        $temp = unpack('H*', $v);
        $v = base_convert($temp[1], 16, 2);
        unset($temp);
    }
    return join(' ',$arr);
}

/**
* binary into string
* @param type $str
* @return type
*/
function binToStr($str){
    $arr = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($arr as &$v){
    $v = pack("H".strlen(base_convert($v, 2, 16)), 
        base_convert($v, 2, 16));
    }
    return join('', $arr);
}
```

but when i test it, the PHP_EOL in .txt file has been mistaken.

code test part:

```
while(!feof($inputFile)){
    $stringOriginal = fread($inputFile,"8");

    //test
    $stringOperated =  binToStr(strToBin($stringOriginal));

    fwrite($ouputFile,$stringOperated,"8");
}
```

Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgNs1.png)

How can I deal with PHP_EOL? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few experiments, I think it's to do with converting the PHP_EOL character to hex and the fact this only produces a single hex digit (a) whereas all the other characters are 2 digit hex numbers.  This seems to confuse it, so the answer I think is down to padding the conversion to hex to ensure they all have 2 chars...

```
function binToStr($str){
    $arr = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($arr as &$v){
        $conv = str_pad(base_convert($v, 2, 16),2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $v = pack("H". strlen($conv), $conv);
    }
    return join('', $arr);
}
```

I've tried this as well, so hopefully this time it will help.

Comment: Inspired by your idea, I try to print the results of each step to the console. then I find out this error happened when file was read. After consulting the relevant information, I realized that I use fread() to get the contents of the .txt file. It won't work when meet the PHP_EOL. So could you please give me more hints about how to read the file? I tried fgets( which stop at PHP_EOL everytime, I don't want it happened) and file_get_contents(it just doesn't work).

Comment: I've updated the code slightly - changed `$conv = str_pad(base_convert($v, 2, 16),2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`, can you try it.  the `fread()` doesn't care about EOL - only EOF.